# Linking two tables in EntityFramework CodeFirst models

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-relationship

I am trying to learn asp.net MVC, by converting a web forms app I have.  It's a room booking app, where there is a customer table (tblCustomerBooking) which has a one to many relationship with tblRental - so one customer can book more than one room.  The fields that match each other are tblCustomerBooking.customer_id -> tblRental.customer_ref

I'm trying to use code first - and building a model class - but I can't figure out how to link the two tables, so that when I query the dbContext, it will return a customer, with one or more rentals within the same model.

My table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCustomerBooking](
    [customer_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [room_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [customer_name] [varchar](110) NULL,
    [customer_email] [varchar](50) NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCustomerBooking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [customer_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRental](
    [rental_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [room_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [check_in] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [check_out] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [customer_ref] [bigint] NULL,
    [room_cost] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblRental_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([rental_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS      =     ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**My attempt at building the model for this is:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions; 
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcApplication23.Models
{
    public class tblRental 
        {
        [Key()]
        public int rental_id { get; set; }
        public int room_id { get; set; } 
            public DateTime check_in { get; set; } 
            public DateTime check_out { get; set; }
            public long customer_ref { get; set; } 
            [ForeignKey("customer_ref")] 
            public tblCustomerBooking Customer {get;set;} 
            public decimal room_cost { get; set; } 
        } 

    public class tblCustomerBooking 
    {
        [Key()]
        public long customer_id { get; set; } 
        public string customer_name { get; set; } 
        public string customer_email { get; set; } 
        public ICollection<tblRental> Rentals {get;set;} 
    }

    public class RentalContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<tblCustomerBooking> customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<tblRental> rentals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        } 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MvcApplication23.Models;

namespace MvcApplication23.api.Controllers
{
    public class RentalController : ApiController
    {
        private RentalContext db = new RentalContext();

        // GET /api/rental/5
        public IQueryable<tblCustomerBooking> Get(int id)
        {
            return db.customers.Include("rentals").FirstOrDefault(c=>c.customer_id==id);
        }
```

** I've updated the info above, with the actual table names that already existed in the database **

How to I link the two tables in the model?  And then given a customer_id, how would I query the DbContext to return a customer, with any related entries in the tblRental table?

Thank you very much for any pointers,

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To link two entities, provide a navigation property:

```
public class Rental
{
    [Key]
    public int rental_id { get; set; }
    public int room_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime check_in { get; set; }
    public DateTime check_out { get; set; }
    public int customer_ref { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("customer_ref")]
    public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;}

    public decimal room_cost { get; set; }
 }

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public string customer_name { get; set; }
    public string customer_email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals {get;set;}
}
```

And to query your customer :

```
return this.DataContext.customers.Include("Rentals").FirstOrDefaul(c=>c.customer_id==customerId);
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this.  It wouldn't work, until I took out the "Vurtual" references in the class.  Now though, when I try the query it states: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcApplication23.Models.Customer' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MvcApplication23.Models.Customer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)... Would anyone be able to clarify what's wrong please?  Thank you.

Comment: @MarkTait : Do you put the FirstOrDefault at the end of your query?

Comment: thank you for replying - yes I did - my controller is: public IQueryable<Customer> Get(int id)
        {
            return db.customers.Include("Rentals").FirstOrDefault(c=>c.customer_id==id);
        }

Comment: @MarkTait : what is the signature of the controller method?

Comment: Hi - it's the API in MVC I'm trying to get to return data: namespace MvcApplication23.api.Controllers
{
    public class RentalController : ApiController
    {
        private RentalContext db = new RentalContext();  // GET /api/rental/5
        public IQueryable<tblCustomerBooking> Get(int id)
        {
            return db.customers.Include("Rentals").FirstOrDefault(c=>c.customer_id==id);
        }

Comment: @MarkTait: it should be: public tblCustomerBooking Get(int id) { return db.customers.Include("Rentals").FirstOrDefault(c=>c.customer_id==id); }

Comment: Hi - I've update the original post, with where I am now - it has some small changes to the customer_ref (which is a bigint in the database, so had to change to long) - I also had to remove Virtual - and the table names have been updates to reflect the actual tables used in the database (which I wasn't aware of, until after I posted originally) - thank you again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12104/discussion-between-gregoire-and-mark-tait)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm now getting an InvalidCastException error on the return db.Customers..... line - it says When casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity - or - Make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type. But I really appreciate all your help to get me this far, and don't want to take up any more of your time. I'll mark your original answer as the "answer" as it has got me a lot further than I've managed myself so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


public class Rental
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int room_id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime check_in { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime check_out { get; set; }
    public virtual int customer_id { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal room_cost { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties
    [ForeignKey("customer_id")]
    public virtual Customer Customer {  get;  set;  }
    #endregion
}

public class Customer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals {get;set;}
}
```